# How do I customize the work items states - customize the list and colors?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2018

I installed TFS 2018 on the premises and I migrated 2 project collections from a TFS 2012 server. I have a hard time finding the page/dialog where I can assign different colors to the work items states. For the previous versions, MS provided visual studio extensions:
[Process Templates Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte), [TFS 2015 Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power&ssr=false#qna). I use VS 2022. I haven't been able to find an extension for editing these lists that would work with VS 2022 and TFS 2018.

Can you please tell me how can I assign different colors to the work items states, and where I can customize the list?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no such an extension ([Process Templates Editor](https://Process%20Templates%20Editor)) for VS 2022.

However, we can export the work item type and process definition files using [witadmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work?view=azure-devops) tool, then customize it with a txt editor, then import the changed files back to your project.

To run the `witadmin` command-line tool, open a Command Prompt window where Visual Studio is installed. The `witadmin` command-line tool installs with any version of Visual Studio.

For Visual Studio 2022, it's under the following path:

```
%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

or `Professional` or `Enterprise` in place of Community, depending on the version you've installed.

> Can you please tell me how can I assign different colors to the work
> items states?

- To set state colors, we can add the property `StateColors` to define the colors. See [Specify properties and behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2022#specify-properties-and-behaviors). Below steps for your reference:

1. Export the process configuration definition file:

`witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:YourProjectName /f:E:\temp\ProcessConfiguration.xml`

2. Open the `ProcessConfiguration.xml` with text editor, add property
   `StateColors` to define the state colors under `Properties` block,
   save the changes.
   [image]
3. Import the process configuration definition back to your project:

`witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:YourProjectName /f:E:\temp\ProcessConfiguration.xml`

4. Check the state colors:

   [image]

> where I can customize the list?

- If you mean add or remove work item states, then you can reference below steps to do that. (Add "`Test`" state for `Task` work item type for example here)

1.Export the Task work item type:

```
witadmin exportwitd /collection: http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:YourProjectName/f:E:\temp\Task.xml
```

2.Open the exported `Task.xml` file with text editor and add a new state `Test` under witd > WORKITEMTYPE > WORKFLOW > STATES:

```
<WORKFLOW>
  <STATES>
    <STATE value="Test">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
```

3.Modify the transitions to go through the new state (Add the transitions as needed, from ="In Progress" to="Test" for example here):

```
<TRANSITIONS>
        <TRANSITION from="In Progress" to="Test">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="Ready to Test" />
          </REASONS>
        </TRANSITION>
```

4.Import the Task definition file:

```
witadmin importwitd /collection: http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:YourProjectName /f:E:\temp\Task.xml
```

5.Check the state list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the commands worked!